# VisualForce Lightning - Proper way to close alert / notification

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I have not been able to find much about this so I just wanted to see if anyone knows the proper way to close a lightning notification displayed in regular VF page using the Salesforce Lightning Design System:

Given the following:

**VF PAGE**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="true" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    

<head>
  <title>My Example Page</title>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
</head>


<body>    

  <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
  <div class="slds">    

    <!-- MASTHEAD -->
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <p class="slds-text-heading--large slds-m-bottom--small slds-text-align--center">
          My header
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- / MASTHEAD -->    

    <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    <div class="myapp">    

        <div class="slds-notify slds-notify--alert slds-theme--inverse-text slds-theme--alert-texture" role="alert">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Info</span>

            <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-notify__close">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2>Base System Alert</h2>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>


</apex:page>
```

When the user clicks on the "X" close icon how should we close the notification?

1. Simply use javascript to set the div to display none?
2. Add a class to hide it
3. Is there a concept similar to data-toggle etc?
4. Anything else

Trying to make the page work in both Classic and Lex

For a Modal, It has classes with the `--open` adding and removing them seems to show and hide the modal but is that the correct way?.

In this case i Guess just calling `.hide()` with jQuery and using a conditionally rendered outputPanel to show it would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLDS (as a seperate thing from Lex) is currently "BYOJS" -- there's no data-toggle or hiding classes baked in, you need to bring all of those yourself, using whatever javascript framework you're using on the page. Someday, Lightning Components MIGHT give us some of that, but you're not working with them anyway! Whatever javascript library you're using on the page, you should use to close the modal in the idiomatic fashion for that library.

Comment: But "How" was the question. Assuming jQuery there is no relationship to the SLDS modal so calling `.close()` does not work.... I believe the answer is as simple as removing the class `slds-fade-in-open` or using `.hide()` but I wanted to make sure..

Comment: Assuming jQuery, just `hide()`ing  the modal should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Your sample markup isn't implementing `.slds-modal-backdrop` though which is key to the consistency of the Lightning design principles. Once you are using that, your javascript should remove the `--open` modifier class too.

Comment: Using `.hide()` does not equate to being able to use `.show()` to show it. So it is not consistent. That is what I am getting at for the core of my question. And I just removed the JS cause it was for the Modal I am working on not the notification in the question (sorry) it was just an example

Comment: So Basically your answer is that we have to find what causes each component to be open (hopefully documented I think) and the figure out a way to implement those features - It may be to remove or add a class, it may be `.hide()` or `.show()` but it will all depend on the component. Does that sum it up?

Comment: Hide and Show just toggle the `display` property of the element. Are you seeing inconsistent behavior with that? That sounds like an issue with your selector. THAT SAID -- SLDS does offer you hide/show helper classes (http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/visibility). You still need to use JS of your choosing to add or remove them, so it's up to you if that's more readable than `hide()` and `show()`. Ultimately, you need a few lines of JS to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm saying. There's not going to be a magic one-liner until SLDS comes with it's own JS (if that ever happens). Right now you just need to dutifully implement the several steps you may need to take.

Comment: For model - Yes, Hide does hide it, but show does not show it (when not open by default). For it to work the modal would have to start out as shown (not ideal) to be able to use `.show()`